# Json Parse issue with error Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, json

I want to parse following json for value of

JSON (saved in my.json):

```
{
"mackoniv":{"entry":"","lastExit":"","userId":"OPENGOVTJOBS","userNick":"mack"},
"johanna":{"entry":"","lastExit":"","userId":"FREEJOBALERT","userNick":"jone"}
}
```

Code used :

```
$json = file_get_contents('my.json');
$json_data = json_decode($json,true);
$userToCheck='johanna';
echo 'userId'.$json_data->$userToCheck->userId;
```

The above code gives error "Trying to get property of non-object", which i understand as $userToCheck isnt an object of $json_data but how do i access the data of "mackoniv" or even "johanna" when userToCheck part is not to be hardcoded.

If i try following way, it gives same error.

```
echo 'userId'.$json_data[$userToCheck]['userId'];
```

Comment: Make sure `my.json` exists and is in your current working directory as [your code otherwise works](https://eval.in/622330).

Comment: When I run this code with EXACTLY the json string you specify it works , but I removed the `,true` from the `json_encode` and used the Object notation syntax to access the PROPERTY `echo 'userId'.$json_data->$userToCheck->userId;`. Therefore the only remaining option is that your `my.json` file does not contain EXACTLY what you specify

Comment: Try adding `echo json_last_error_msg ()` after the `json_decode()` line to see if there is an error reported that shines some light on this issue

Answer (score 0):

first of all `json_decode($jsondata, true);` would return an array. try to var_dump your $json to make sure you've got the file and then var_dump $json_data.

Answer (score 0):

If you write it like below it should work.

```
        $json = file_get_contents('my.json');
        $json_data = json_decode($json, true);
        $userToCheck = 'johanna';
        echo 'userId = ' . $json_data[$userToCheck]['userId'];
```

Basically change the line:

```
echo 'userId' . $json_data->$userToCheck->userId;
```

with:

```
echo 'userId = ' . $json_data[$userToCheck]['userId'];
```

Answer (score 0):

if json_decode second paramether is true, it returns an array, if it is false (default), returns an object. So, if you want to use it as an object, just decode it like: `$json_data = json_decode($json);`. If this doesn't work, check what `echo json_last_error_msg();` returns. If it returns "No error", then the problem is that your file_get_contents() is not refering to the correct file.